# PHP7.0 & Informix DB connectors

Tags: pdo, informix, php-7

I am trying to connect to an Informix db remotely via php7.0
I've found the driver 
https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_INFORMIX/1.3.3

Downloaded the .tar.gz. and extracted it.
Prepped the php files via phpize and ran ./configure as explained in:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.php

However, it crashes with the following error:

checking for PDO includes... configure: error: Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h.

I know that PDO has been a core PHP lib for a while and probably the C header file is named differently than the one referenced in the lib.

Any ideas where to go from here?
It's been a very rough day.
Installing the Informix SDK is a nightmare for itself anyway. Can't even find the installation dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Informix SDK has been carefully and specifically designed by IBM to ruin your day.

- The whole set lives under `/opt/IBM/informix` by default
- Add `/opt/IBM/informix/lib/cli` and `/opt/IBM/informix/lib/esql` to your dynamic linker lookup paths. On Fedora you can do this by putting them in a new file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/informix.conf`
- You need to set the environment variable `INFORMIXDIR`. On Fedora you may add a new file `/etc/profile.d/informix.sh` and add `export INFORMIXDIR=/opt/IBM/informix`
- Edit `/opt/IBM/informix/etc/sqlhosts` and put your basic connection information there. In the most simple case it has only one line that reads `YOUR_SERVER_NAME\tonsoctcp\tYOUR_DB_NAME\tpdap-np`. Note that `pdap-np` is actually port 1526 which is also the Informix "Turbo"-Driver tcp port. See your `/etc/services`.
- Get the environment-changes going, e.g. by a reboot if you did them globally.
- I can't remember the include-dir but you probably need `/opt/IBM/informix/include` in your `CFLAGS`'s `-I`

Comment: Haven't really gotten that far yet :)
At the moment I'm still having issues installing the CSDK. I'm getting errors saying I don't have the appropriate Java version, yet I've updated all sys libs.

Installing the PDO_INFORMIX for php can't be done without the CSDK, so I haven't even bothered with it yet.
The CSDK takes up a lot of space o_o.

Do you perhaps know what I have to do to get the appropriate java version for the csdk? I'm running on Ubuntu

Comment: I can't tell. But the CSDK's installation program comes with a bundled Java interpreter that should get used automatically - maybe if you deinstall / hide your system-java, you can get it to work

Comment: Thanks for the help I'll try that :)