# HOw Install PDO Driver Informix for PHP 7 in Windows

Tags: php, pdo, informix

In my work they have as a business core a database in informix, which limits the range of action in terms of web programming. Therefore the productive machines are in windows with PHP 5.2 for the compatibility with informix. The problem with this is that most PHP frameworks are migrating to PHP 7, and natively they are limited to Informix connections. The question is, can I install the pdo driver for Informix in PHP 7 with windows server?

ODBC Successful connection.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP7.0 & Informix DB connectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972106/php7-0-informix-db-connectors)

Comment: Duplicate says so for Linux but since your question is literately `can I install the pdo driver for Informix in PHP 7 with windows server?` I'm going to say Yes but looks like it may be a bit painful

Comment: You may also want to check out; https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_INFORMIX

Comment: As additional information I have installed and running the connection in ODBC. Will there be an alternative solution?

Comment: Latest release of the PDO_INFORMIX is 1.3.3 (2017).
Apparently, support for PHP 7, was added in 1.3.2 so it should work, but you may need to build the library (DLL) yourself,   
as the last prebuild on Windows was done with 1.3.1

Comment: Which flavour of PHP (32-bit or 64-bit) are you running? Thread-Safe or Non Thread-Safe?

Comment: How can I perform this procedure to compile the dll? some link?

Comment: Thread Safe Enabled

Comment: There are some instructions in the module page (http://php.net/pdo-informix) but hasn't been updated in ages. I did built on Windows some time ago. It's not difficult, but you need to have all the components in place. 32 or 64 ? 8)

Comment: Solved!, with pre compilated dll in PHP 7.1 TS. Link to precompiled dll https://github.com/Aevis/php_pdo_informix

Answer (score 2):

Solved!, with pre compilated dll in PHP 7.1 TS. Link to precompiled dll https://github.com/Aevis/php_pdo_informix . Thanks!!!!

Comment: It only works for x86 platform, not x64, unfortunately